# JSch to copy directory from local to remote Linux machine

Tags: linux, jsch

In JSch, i found a very helpful [example code](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html) which copies a file from local machine to remote Linux machine. Is there any way to copy directory from local to remote Linux machine using Jsch?

OR

Do i need to loop thorough all the files one by one and copy it to remote machine?

Comment: I worked with JSCH but I didn't come across copying entire folder.So, you need to follow second approach you mentioned in the question.http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/ssh/ScpToMessage.java?revision=579266&view=co.Check this link.May be you can write your code based on this.

Comment: @SrinivasR: Not able to open the link `400 Bad Request` . Can you please resend the link?

Comment: Basically I got this link from here So check this out whether it's help ful to you  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jsch/845